# Sanity check: Architecture for designing views that work in both iOS and OSX?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

I'm building an app for which I'd like to reuse 99% of the code in iOS and OSX. Just asking for a sanity check.

**(Edit)** A bit more information about my project that may affect some of the responses: My app involves a customizable presentation that's primarily intended for iOS devices. The OSX component is actually a designer for the customizable presentation - a way of specifying what is to be presented on a selected iOS device. That is, the OSX app will be a completely normal OSX app that allows the user to choose, configure, and position some elements for the iOS device - and that displays a preview of that presentation. Of course, I want the preview to resemble the iOS rendering as closely as possible (without actually invoking the iOS simulator, which I don't expect to be available on all OSX devices). So I've designed the presentation as a view that should be rendered as-nearly-identically-as-possible on both OSX and iOS.

To this end, I started in iOS with some simple view-drawing stuff, and now I'm reconfiguring the code so that I can port it to OSX. My strategy so far is to replace all references to UIView / UIWindow / UIFont / UIColor etc. with _View / _Window / _Font / _Color, etc. For the iOS version, I'll include a file called Wrapper.h like this:

```
#define _Device UIDevice
#define _Application UIApplication
#define _ApplicationMain UIApplicationMain
#define _ApplicationDelegate UIApplicationDelegate
#define _Responder UIResponder
#define _Window UIWindow
```

...with NS-based definitions for OSX (NSWindows, etc.) I know that a few details will change (like Y coordinates in views), but I can deal with that.

The only components that I don't think I can map like that are gesture recognizers, since OSX has no equivalent. I'm planning to make them a generic call that's implemented in the iOS wrapper, and stubbed out in the OSX wrapper, since I really don't need tap events in OSX.

Good idea? Bad idea? Is there a better way to tackle this? Thanks...

Comment: Have you actually tried it yet? I think your 99% of code reuse goal is severely optimistic. Normally desktop apps are not just exact copies of iOS apps. This question is also posed in a way that it is difficult to give a correct answer.

Comment: Most of the code is platform-independent logic resulting in some pretty basic UIKit calls to NSBezierPath, etc. It's just drawing in a view.

I'm trying it now, and the only significant problems I'm encountering are with a few UIWebBrowser controls. OSX has a WebKit API with a WebBrowser control that works similarly, but not quite the same. Will just throw a wrapper around it in my Helper function to expose either a UIWebBrowser or a WebBrowser and translate calls accordingly.

Comment: Ok, if you are using a web browser to help with portability and your app doesn't use a lot of UIKit, then I would say go for it, and then come back to ask specific questions where you get hung up on things. That tends to get you better answers.

Comment: need more idea what you are implementing.

Comment: @DavidStein: I think you'll find doing this will be much harder than you imagined. Just a warning. ;)

Answer (score 5):

> My strategy so far is to replace all references to UIView / UIWindow /
>   UIFont / UIColor etc. with _View / _Window / _Font / _Color, etc.

UIKit is not just AppKit with all the occurrences of "NS" changed to "UI". While there are strong similarities, there are also important differences both in the way the frameworks work and in the way users expect to use software written with each framework. Is it possible to write a single framework that's implemented in terms of both UIKit and AppKit? Undoubtedly, but you'll end up with something that prevents you from taking full advantage of either platform.

> Good idea? Bad idea? Is there a better way to tackle this?

IMO, bad idea. If you do a good job designing your data model, you should be able to share that between the Mac and iOS implementations with no changes. Then, instead of spending a lot of time trying to figure out how to write a single user interface and coming up with something that's a compromise on both sides, put that effort into creating separate user interfaces that are compelling on both platforms.

Comment: I understand and appreciate your recommendation. My project is a bit peculiar, though, and I believe that the details may alter your evaluation. Would you mind taking a look at my updated project summary and letting me know what you think?

Comment: For the purpose of doing some custom drawing that looks the same on both platforms, it might be reasonable to write one or more views that build as a UIView on iOS and a NSView on MacOS X. Core Graphics is available on both platforms, so it's easy to use the same (CG) drawing code on both. But it's not going to take you long to discover that many classes are quite different between the two frameworks. UIFont isn't just NSFont with a different name; UIWindow has 9 methods while NSWindow has dozens.